# Filter by sub node with product count

Tags: sql

The following SQL code is working correctly, but I can not select / filter category. Brings all of the categories.

As an example,

```
Cars (20) (root)
---> Blue cars (12)
----------> Ford (2)
----------> Bmw (9)
----------> Dodge (1)
---> Red cars (9)
----------> Xxxx (9)
---> Black cars (1)
----------> Yy (1)
```

How do I select only the category of the blue car. (with subnodes)

How do I change the sql code for this can be done?

I want the result to be as follows. (If I choose blue car category)

```
---> blue cars (12)
----------> ford (2)
----------> bmw (9)
----------> dodge (1)
```

This is the sql code ...

```
SELECT 
parent.cid,
parent.title,
(SELECT COUNT(parent2.cid) FROM categories AS parent2 WHERE parent.lft > parent2.lft AND parent.rgt < parent2.rgt) AS depth,
COUNT(products.cat_id) AS total

FROM categories AS node,
categories AS parent,
products

WHERE 

node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 

AND node.cid = products.cat_id

GROUP BY parent.cid having depth <= 5
ORDER BY parent.lft
```

Comment: How are you storing your heirachy? - see this question for your options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: I think all you need to do is to add `AND node.cid=` (the whatever cid is the id for the Blue Cars)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have been overthinking this - getting the subtree is about the simplist operation for nested sets

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
WHERE lft BETWEEN bluecarleftvalue AND bluecarrightvalue
ORDER BY lft ASC
```

Comment: basically yes. but I need to count the products.

Comment: What is the link between categories and products?